# Apply UI for jQuery tabs earlier?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this page: http://www.shopdesertridge.com/events/full-calendar/

If you are loading it, you will notice for a while that "May" tab is blue while the page is loading and **the proper style** (js method) is called **AFTER** the content of the page was loaded.

Do you know any trick to make this UI styling earlier?

For asp.net programmers: that TAB is a repeater with specific months so I even tried calling the js method when `ItemDataBound` but the result is the same like when calling it on document ready...

The js to render the tabs' UI:

```
function tabsUi(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective way to have the styles apply faster is to include the required classes directly in the markup.

```
<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
   <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab one content goes here.</p>
   </div>
    ...
</div>
```

This way the content will be styled as soon as the css is loaded rather than waiting for the DOMReady event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `display:none` by default, then `tabs()`, and then `show()`

```
<div id="tabs" style="display:none">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">1</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">3</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        $( "#tabs" ).show();
    });
</script>​
```